# Developing an image gallery or content slider without any jQuery (or Flash)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, slider, gallery

First post, but I've been lurking around this site for a long while now, and I know how good some of you guys are at this development game.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to develop a gallery/mainnav widget for the top of a landing page, but the page cannot include the jQuery library or any flash objects. I haven't explicitly checked yet, but I don't think mootools will work either. Having said that, I am by far most familiar with building stuff like this using jQuery than any other libraries out there right now, so having had that taken away is proving a difficult obstacle for me.

I'm looking for ideas/suggestions/direction on possibly trying to build something like this using a canvas element (my canvas skills are not that well developed yet, fyi) or if a pure-javascript solution is available somewhere... or really any input that I may not have considered yet.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If the reason you can't use jQuery is another JS library that defines $, you can use jQuery in .noConflict() mode

Comment: If you'd learned JavaScript from the ground up before/without using shortcuts like jQuery, you'd be able to build a pure-JS solution to any problem.

Comment: @Kolink Yep. Whether this is a good idea or not is debatable.

Comment: @Koling I kinda entered JS development backwards. Started with design, learned html and css, then learned barebones JS just enough to use jQuery. Used that pretty exclusivly for a while until it became apparent that I needed more basic JS understanding. I'm working on it.. but still have a ways to go.

Comment: @relic180 That's more typical than you'd think these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably conflicting with another library, in which case you can use jQuery in [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

Developing something so UI-heavy without jQuery or some other framework is really not advisable. It will likely take much longer to build, with much longer and less maintainable code that works across fewer browsers.

Comment: I disagree with your advice not to develop something UI-heavy without a framework. In my opinion, the more UI-heavy it is, the more it should be in pure JS. Heck, just something as simple as `$('ul > li.green').css({color:'green'});` takes over 80 code steps per element matched, whereas the same in pure JS takes just 4 per element. Scale that up with heavy UI, and the difference becomes thousands.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I can't use jQuery or Flash are business politics. What I've been working on is figuring out if there a technical reason for that business decision, but haven't gotten an adequate response back yet. Until then, I'm just trying to figure out how I might do this if jQuery remains off the table.